# Php File Download Filesize

Tags: php, file-get-contents, filesize

```
$url = $_GET['fileurl'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($url);

$ext = $path_parts['extension'];
$filename = $path_parts['filename'];

header("Content-type: video/$ext");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.mp4");

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

When the download starts, it does not show the user actual size of the file.. File Size shows only Unknown. So what should I do right now?

Comment: set the Content-Length header

Comment: Can you please explain it by coding?

Comment: no I won't. you can see it in th duplicate question I linked.

Comment: I have tried to understand a little bit. Now my code looks like this:-
$url = $_GET['fileurl'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($url);

$ext = $path_parts['extension'];
$filename = $path_parts['filename'];

header("Content-type: video/$ext");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.mp4");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($url));

echo file_get_contents($url);


But it works the same as it was working previously! :(

Comment: What is the mistake in it?